# How to get windows app directory in React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rxjs

How to get windows app directory in React JS
I am getting relative path here, I would like to get absolute path so in further processing

```
  var os = require('os');
  var home = os.userdir();
```

also tried to use

```
import getAppDataPath from "appdata-path";
console.log(getAppDataPath());
```

also

```
let localAppData = process.env.APPDATA || (process.platform == 'darwin' ? process.env.HOME + '/Library/Preferences' : process.env.HOME + "/.local/share");
```

like to have path like this, %temp% / %appdir%

C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local OR
C:\Users<user> \AppData\Local\Temp

I am getting
/.config
/tmp

Comment: Have you tried `process.env.TEMP`?

Comment: process.env.TEMP , this return empty